# Conveying that a card linked to a gallery has multiple photos instead of one

Tags: cards

I'm creating a card view in which each card is linked to a separate view which contains either one photo or multiple photos. The resulting view is not necessarily a gallery, but more of an asset type view in which each asset will have a preview of some sort.

Currently, the main preview image for each card is a single preview of the first asset within the linked view. I'm trying to explore a more visually captivating and elegant way of showing the user more than one preview for these cards that are linked to views that contain more than 1 photo/asset.

Examples I've worked through are shown within attached screenshot. Would love your thoughts on alternatives or a suggested path. Thank you.

[image]

Comment: I wonder what in your opinion the cons/downsides are to the last option (single photo with floating indicator), because that is the option that I would personally go for. I designed (album) cards like this before, and almost always opted for [something similar](https://i.imgur.com/qBWfYaJ.png).

Comment: In addition, the other options are nice in the way that they add some flare and stand out, but they also heavily add to the user's cognitive load, because there is a lot more to see and take in. A visual indicator that is always in the same place, and only visible when relevant (1+ images) sounds like the obvious answer to me :)

Comment: I think Spotify playlists (of mixed albums/artists) use a 2x2 mosaic of the first four items - That might be worth including in your investigations.

Comment: @JosvanWeesel great point on the cognitive load and consistency in representation.

Comment: @RouxMartin I'll see if I can find that for reference, thank you.

Comment: When you're creating a card view in which each card is linked to a separate view which contains either one photo or multiple photos;
the resulting view is not necessarily a gallery, but more of an asset type view; each asset will have a preview of some sort… what application are you using. Come to that, what generic type of app are you using?

Answer (score 1):

One approach is to allow users to glance at the visual information first. Is there a reason not to allow users to view images first?

If it's desirable (or possible) to have a user glance at the photos *without commitment* to navigating to the details of a card, you have a couple of options:

[image]

For the badge approach, you don't have to allow them to explore the images, but they'll still see there's more than one.

Comment: This is certainly an option I can explore. I like that there is consistency in the dimensions of the preview, and there are simply options added if there is more than one photo. My only issue is that if the linked view contains 50+ photos, I'm not so sure we'd have the ability to load up a high number of cards that could each contain a high number of photos.

Comment: In that case the option for ecommerce could have several thumbnails, and some text that says '+ 20' to indicate there's more. You could also just load several, and then have a 'view all' as well